# Communication over USB

Tags: android, usb

In many posts i have seen that since Android 3.1 it is possible to have a device as an USB host. While this is nice its not actually the functionality i need. All i need to have is communication over the USB port of the device, which means sending and receiving commands. Who acts as host in this scenario is not important for me, the PC can be the host and my device the client. Is there a functionality with android that allows me to send commands over the usb port and receive answers from the other end (in the current case my computer and an application that listens on the USB ports for devices).

I have tried the approach where my device is the host (its an Asus Transformer Pad) using the uses-feature in the manifest, but UsbManager.getDeviceList returns me an empty device no matter whats connected to the device (the dock, the PC, another android device).

Answer (score 0):

I know of some programs that us the ADB

So that might be an option for you depending on what you would like to do.

check here: http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=ADB

Comment: Thanks for your tip, i had a look at the samples in the android SDK, there i have a little problem, it has the following line: for (UsbDevice device :  mManager.getDeviceList().values()). Now the problem is that in my application mManager.getDeviceList().size() == 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an USB data transfer cable (also called USB data link cable) which support API or SDK, then use the following code. Communication speed much faster than using WinSock(TCP/IP) over USB or serial port over USB. USB2.0 communication speed is 480Mbps, effective data communication speeds greater than 100Mbps, and can isolate viruses and network attacks.

```
void CU2uDlg::OnOK() 
{
BYTE        buf[65530];
LPU2URET    pU2uRet;
BOOL        bRet;
int         ret;
CString     msgstr;

ret = u2u_open();
if (ret == -1){
    AfxMessageBox("Open U2U device Success.");
}else{
    msgstr.Format("Open U2U device fail，return：%d", ret);
    AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
    return;
}

//send data
bRet = u2u_SendData(buf, 65530, ret);
if(!bRet)
{
    msgstr.Format("Send data error，return：%d", ret);
    AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
    return;
}

//receive data
while (1){
    bRet = u2u_RecvData(recvData, dataLen, ret);
    if( !bRet )
    {
        msgstr.Format("Receive data error，return：%d", ret);
        AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
        u2u_close();
        return;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
u2u_close();


}
```

See:
[Reference1](http://www.cnblogs.com/LiuKaiFa/p/USB_data_link_cable_API.html), [Reference2](http://blog.csdn.net/zzkjliu/article/details/12838383)